# A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, isolation-level, alerts, error-log

A few days ago, in one of my servers, I had the following alert pop out:

> A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the
>   client. A common cause for this is if the application is running in
>   READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level. This connection will be terminated.

However, it has only happened once, and I could not deal with it there and then.

where/how could I search for more information as to what was the primary cause(s) that triggered this alert/message?

**Edit**

Actually this question could be something down these lines:

what should I query at the time the alert was fired, to add more information to the email the DBAs get?

Comment: Please read last section of  [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic433355-149-1.aspx) and [this](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH233084.html).

Comment: I had had a look at the first link previously and it seems it may be the same situation here, thanks for posting. However, I would like to find out where this nolock is, inside what procedure or ad hoc statement, or maybe a package somewhere _grrr_ I am hunting for more info, even if I wanted to add more info into the alert for the next time it fires...

Comment: What isolation level you are using?

Comment: snaphot is not enabled, it is all read committed

Comment: Depending on your PLE, you may have been able to pull plans from cache where the keyword "NOLOCK" was used.  Don't know if that's truly your cause or not, but next time this alert is thrown maybe a quick search through your cache can help you identify the statement or eliminate the NOLOCK hint from the list of potential causes.